# How to fit wide and long table to text width?

Tags: tables, longtable

I iried using longtable but it is too wide for the page. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
    \usepackage{booktabs, dcolumn, makecell,               
        longtable, tabularx}
 \usepackage{siunitx}
 \usepackage{setspace}        

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{S[table-format=2.0]
        *{10}{S[table-format=2.1]}
        S[table-format=2.1,detect-weight]
    }
    \caption{}
    \label{tab:summary_camp_MAC} \\
    \toprule
    {Survey site code}& {Long GB (m)}& {Lat GB (m)} &{Geol. fm.}& {Sandtone(\%)}& {Siltstone(\%)}&{$R_{site(obs)}$} & {$R_{site(obs)IQR}$}& {$ Mv\%$}& {GSI}\\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    \caption[]{}\\        
    \toprule
    {Survey site code}& {Long GB (m)}& {Lat GB (m)} &{Geol. fm.}& {Sandtone(\%)}& {Siltstone(\%)}&{$R_{site(obs)}$} & {$R_{site(obs)IQR}$}& {$ Mv\%$}& {GSI}\\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \multicolumn{10}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continued on the next page}}
    \endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    20160007    &   1607690 &   4885250 &   MAC &   100 &       &   15.4    &   3.9 &   8.3 &   -9999   &   \\
    20160008    &   1616420 &   4892160 &   MAC &   100 &       &   11.8    &   13.9    &   32.7    &   35  &   \\
    20160009    &   1617450 &   4892970 &   MAC &   100 &       &   12.9    &   6.4 &   12.3    &   -9999   &   \\
    20160028    &   1642450 &   4867020 &   MAC &   80  &   20  &   11.8    &   4.8 &   33.3    &   45  &   \\
    20160054    &   1607510 &   4895540 &   MAC &   100 &       &   9.4 &   5.8 &   26.0    &   40  &   \\
    20160055    &   1651750 &   4855650 &   MAC &   85  &   15  &   6.4 &   3.5 &   60.5    &   15  &   \\
    20160058    &   1599670 &   4899700 &   MAC &   100 &       &   16.1    &   10.2    &   24.3    &   35  &   \\
    20160064    &   1613750 &   4875080 &   MAC &   100 &       &   8.9 &   6.4 &   40.5    &   40  &   \\
    20160065    &   1628850 &   4875430 &   MAC &   100 &       &   19.9    &   9.1 &   18.0    &   50  &   \\
    20160067    &   1626270 &   4880370 &   MAC &   100 &       &   10.9    &   7.9 &   31.5    &   40  &   \\
    20160089    &   1579370 &   4907480 &   MAC &   100 &       &   17.3    &   6.3 &   18.5    &   35  &   \\
    20160094    &   1626920 &   4864650 &   MAC &   85  &   15  &   15.4    &   4.9 &   11.8    &   45  &   \\
    20160099    &   1615920 &   4891250 &   MAC &   100 &       &   11.8    &   10.3    &   29.5    &   40  &   \\
    20160102    &   1608230 &   4883910 &   MAC &       &       &   11.3    &   13.4    &   30.3    &   50  &   \\
    20160103    &   1630270 &   4874830 &   MAC &   100 &       &   11.2    &   9.8 &   27.3    &   40  &   \\
    20160111    &   1637300 &   4866700 &   MAC &   100 &       &   26.3    &   5.8 &   2.5 &   50  &   \\
    20160116    &   1635020 &   4887380 &   MAC &   100 &       &   24.6    &   7.6 &   5.8 &   45  &   \\
    20160125    &   1638850 &   4861050 &   MAC &   100 &       &   12.9    &   9.4 &   55.5    &   35  &   \\
    20160126    &   1632580 &   4875200 &   MAC &   100 &       &   17.7    &   9.9 &   16.3    &   45  &   \\
    20160132    &   1627950 &   4879380 &   MAC &   100 &       &   23.7    &   13.7    &   9.0 &   70  &   \\
    20160140    &   1629620 &   4876660 &   MAC &   100 &       &   12.4    &   6.2 &   23.3    &   45  &   \\
    20160161    &   1612630 &   4892280 &   MAC &   90  &   10  &   10.6    &   8.1 &   37.8    &   40  &   \\
    20160179    &   1633200 &   4874750 &   MAC &   100 &       &   15.8    &   16.5    &   22.3    &   45  &   \\
    20160180    &   1629130 &   4877660 &   MAC &   20  &       &   11.7    &   13.4    &   36.8    &   35  &   \\
    20160187    &   1609870 &   4886470 &   MAC &   100 &       &   34.5    &   9.0 &   1.3 &   60  &   \\
    20160189    &   1616110 &   4883040 &   MAC &   100 &       &   32.9    &   3.1 &   0.3 &   60  &   \\
    20160190    &   1639440 &   4884930 &   MAC &       &   30  &   8.6 &   6.1 &   46.5    &   45  &   \\
    20160192    &   1621280 &   4882190 &   MAC &   100 &       &   28.3    &   8.3 &   0.3 &   60  &   \\
    20160199    &   1617480 &   4892980 &   MAC &   100 &       &   21.0    &   7.4 &   1.3 &   50  &   \\
    20160212    &   1623080 &   4886120 &   MAC &   95  &       &   15.6    &   3.7 &   3.3 &   40  &   \\
    20160215    &   1635030 &   4871590 &   MAC &   50  &   10  &   15.3    &   6.2 &   7.0 &   35  &   \\
    20160216    &   1633810 &   4873860 &   MAC &   100 &       &   14.2    &   5.9 &   7.5 &   35  &   \\
    20160228    &   1611490 &   4888050 &   MAC &   90  &       &   28.7    &   17.5    &   4.5 &   60  &   \\
    20160230    &   1611900 &   4886400 &   MAC &   100 &       &   24.4    &   15.2    &   1.8 &   50  &   \\
    20160234    &   1649360 &   4859070 &   MAC &   100 &       &   30.0    &   7.4 &   0.0 &   50  &   \\
    20160240    &   1628280 &   4885520 &   MAC &   100 &       &   27.5    &   10.4    &   6.3 &   50  &   \\
    20160245    &   1606850 &   4886800 &   MAC &   95  &       &   31.6    &   10.3    &   1.3 &   50  &   \\
    20160248    &   1604840 &   4897570 &   MAC &   100 &       &   24.7    &   6.5 &   10.0    &   50  &   \\
    20160252    &   1604300 &   4899930 &   MAC &   100 &       &   27.2    &   11.4    &   1.3 &   55  &   \\
    20160256    &   1610880 &   4872490 &   MAC &   80  &   20  &   24.0    &   7.6 &   20.5    &   45  &   \\
    20160257    &   1603610 &   4889240 &   MAC &   100 &       &   30.0    &   4.2 &   0.0 &   65  &   \\
    20160264    &   1617530 &   4890220 &   MAC &   100 &       &   32.3    &   6.7 &   0.0 &   60  &   \\
    20160267    &   1632780 &   4889010 &   MAC &   40  &       &   13.7    &   17.3    &   24.3    &   40  &   \\
    20160272    &   1636910 &   4887220 &   MAC &   100 &       &   27.8    &   8.0 &   2.3 &   55  &   \\
    20160277    &   1589240 &   4878450 &   MAC &   100 &       &   10.5    &   7.2 &   24.3    &   30  &   \\
    20160278    &   1589630 &   4878030 &   MAC &   100 &       &   11.3    &   6.1 &   22.3    &   -9999   &   \\
    20160279    &   1589360 &   4878090 &   MAC &       &       &   14.9    &   9.7 &   21.8    &   -9999   &   \\
    20160280    &   1589200 &   4878190 &   MAC &   100 &       &   15.8    &   4.1 &   1.5 &   50  &   \\
    20160281    &   1588690 &   4878380 &   MAC &   100 &       &   9.1 &   6.2 &   35.5    &   30  &   \\
    20160283    &   1586320 &   4881360 &   MAC &   100 &       &   17.7    &   15.0    &   16.0    &   45  &   \\
    20160284    &   1585980 &   4881540 &   MAC &   80  &       &   17.3    &   5.5 &   2.8 &   45  &   \\
    20160286    &   1588290 &   4878570 &   MAC &   100 &       &   19.1    &   6.2 &   1.5 &   55  &   \\
    20170292    &   1592500 &   4892430 &   MAC &       &       &   19.2    &   7.8 &   1.8 &   -9999   &   \\
    20170293    &   1593630 &   4895890 &   MAC &   100 &       &   28.8    &   7.9 &   0.0 &   -9999   &   \\
    20170294    &   1592590 &   4896460 &   MAC &   100 &       &   31.0    &   6.9 &   0.0 &   -9999   &   \\
    20170295    &   1592350 &   4896370 &   MAC &   100 &       &   19.7    &   9.9 &   3.5 &   -9999   &   \\
    20170296    &   1592380 &   4905810 &   MAC &   100 &       &   29.0    &   8.0 &   0.0 &   -9999   &   \\
    20170297    &   1592400 &   4907000 &   MAC &   70  &       &   15.0    &   13.3    &   31.8    &   -9999   &   \\
    20170298    &   1592170 &   4906530 &   MAC &   70  &       &   10.1    &   12.3    &   45.3    &   -9999   &   \\
    20170299    &   1594910 &   4891490 &   MAC &   90  &       &   29.7    &   9.9 &   0.3 &   -9999   &   \\
    20170300    &   1585800 &   4887720 &   MAC &   90  &       &   31.1    &   6.3 &   2.3 &   -9999   &   \\
    20170302    &   1584720 &   4886610 &   MAC &   75  &       &   30.0    &   11.6    &   3.8 &   -9999   &   \\
    20170303    &   1592340 &   4891340 &   MAC &   60  &       &   27.7    &   11.9    &   5.5 &   -9999   &   \\
    20170304    &   1584520 &   4885990 &   MAC &   85  &       &   18.6    &   5.0 &   4.0 &   -9999   &   \\
    20170305    &   1579960 &   4888640 &   MAC &   100 &       &   16.0    &   6.8 &   2.0 &   -9999   &   \\
    20170306    &   1582470 &   4887480 &   MAC &   100 &       &   12.8    &   3.2 &   1.3 &   -9999   &   \\
    20170311    &   1572640 &   4900500 &   MAC &   85  &   15  &   32.3    &   17.0    &   9.0 &   -9999   &   \\
    20170312    &   1569670 &   4900420 &   MAC &   95  &       &   41.5    &   5.6 &   0.0 &   -9999   &   \\
    20170313    &   1568040 &   4908720 &   MAC &   90  &       &   38.4    &   13.1    &   3.8 &   -9999   &   \\
    20170314    &   1569090 &   4909490 &   MAC &   80  &   20  &   29.2    &   9.3 &   6.8 &   -9999   &   \\
    20170315    &   1570460 &   4907080 &   MAC &   50  &       &   22.5    &   11.5    &   1.8 &   -9999   &   \\
    20170319    &   1568360 &   4905170 &   MAC &   70  &   30  &   7.2 &   5.4 &   45.8    &   -9999   &   \\
    20170320    &   1587250 &   4908030 &   MAC &   90  &   10  &   24.0    &   13.8    &   19.8    &   -9999   &   \\
    20170321    &   1577010 &   4912650 &   MAC &   100 &       &   21.0    &   6.1 &   0.3 &   -9999   &   \\
    20170322    &   1569040 &   4911210 &   MAC &   95  &       &   12.9    &   5.0 &   12.0    &   -9999   &   \\
    20170324    &   1567700 &   4910090 &   MAC &   100 &       &   21.9    &   7.3 &   0.5 &   -9999   &   \\
    20170325    &   1575160 &   4913620 &   MAC &   100 &       &   24.5    &   16.8    &   16.8    &   -9999   &   \\
    20170326    &   1578770 &   4913330 &   MAC &   100 &       &   21.7    &   12.8    &   2.3 &   -9999   &   \\
    20170327    &   1583430 &   4909340 &   MAC &   100 &       &   27.5    &   7.4 &   0.8 &   -9999   &   \\
    20170328    &   1564440 &   4909900 &   MAC &   100 &       &   23.5    &   5.4 &   0.0 &   -9999   &   \\
    20170329    &   1561890 &   4910980 &   MAC &   100 &       &   32.7    &   7.9 &   0.3 &   -9999   &   \\
    20170330    &   1558500 &   4909390 &   MAC &   100 &       &   25.2    &   8.4 &   0.0 &   -9999   &   \\
    20170331    &   1564360 &   4907210 &   MAC &   100 &       &   19.6    &   19.7    &   23.5    &   -9999   &   \\
    20170332    &   1571290 &   4918160 &   MAC &   100 &       &   28.8    &   6.6 &   2.3 &   -9999   &   \\
    20170333    &   1570430 &   4918290 &   MAC &   95  &       &   23.6    &   5.6 &   0.0 &   -9999   &   \\
    20170334    &   1565530 &   4919120 &   MAC &   90  &       &   18.4    &   8.7 &   20.5    &   -9999   &   \\
    20170335    &   1565100 &   4915610 &   MAC &   100 &       &   15.1    &   6.8 &   9.8 &   -9999   &   \\
    20170336    &   1568760 &   4918440 &   MAC &   100 &       &   26.5    &   13.9    &   12.0    &   -9999   &   \\
    20170337    &   1563570 &   4906190 &   MAC &   100 &       &   24.8    &   7.5 &   1.5 &   -9999   &   \\
    20170341    &   1579920 &   4890580 &   MAC &   100 &       &   28.6    &   4.5 &   0.3 &   -9999   &   \\
    20170342    &   1579640 &   4891250 &   MAC &   100 &       &   18.8    &   11.2    &   73.8    &   -9999   &   \\
    20170344    &   1589220 &   4890470 &   MAC &   100 &       &   25.9    &   8.0 &   1.0 &   -9999   &   \\
    20170346    &   1572260 &   4918250 &   MAC &   100 &       &   19.3    &   12.0    &   18.8    &   -9999   &   \\
    20170347    &   1575560 &   4919100 &   MAC &   100 &       &   30.7    &   12.6    &   0.3 &   -9999   &   \\
    20171007    &   1592610 &   4905140 &   MAC &   100 &       &   25.1    &   6.4 &   2.8 &   50  &   \\
    20171015    &   1594430 &   4895710 &   MAC &   100 &       &   16.7    &   12.3    &   14.5    &   35  &   \\
    20171016    &   1594060 &   4892390 &   MAC &   100 &       &   16.9    &   7.2 &   11.5    &   40  &   \\
    20171017    &   1593560 &   4892350 &   MAC &   100 &       &   16.9    &   7.2 &   11.5    &   50  &   \\
    20171020    &   1569820 &   4908340 &   MAC &   100 &       &   27.6    &   5.0 &   0.5 &   60  &   \\
    20171021    &   1568030 &   4907030 &   MAC &   100 &       &   23.2    &   11.2    &   1.0 &   45  &   \\
    20171022    &   1567060 &   4905870 &   MAC &   50  &   40  &   17.5    &   23.8    &   38.3    &   35  &   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\onehalfspacing
\end{document}
```

Comment: `siunitx` and `setspace` are missing to make your code compilable. Please also make sure you double check the values of `table-format` as they don't match the numbers currently present in the corresponding columns.

Comment: Even with a very small font size, it might be hard to make your table fit into the textwidth of a portrait page. Maybe try with a landscape page instead?

Comment: @leandriis now it's ok. Do you mean the number of columns? they are 10.

Comment: First step: Remove the headers and make sure that the table data typesets correctly and within the page width. Currently your column specifiers are not suitable for the data in the columns. After that, think about how you can abbreviate the header, and/or shrink its font, and/or split it over two lines such that the columns don't get wider.

Comment: Try with `\scriptsize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.25em}` and place these commands before `\begin{longtable}`

Comment: @Elisam: The number of columns is ok. but `S[table-format=2.0]` simply is not correct regarding the contents of the first column.

Comment: all the suggestions are working perfectly. Really thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With small reformatting of the your table it can be fit in portrait page orientation and using normal font size. For example, remove column, which all cells have the same value and its purpose explain in table caption, use abbreviation for columns' headers and in legend added to caption explain their meaning:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable, makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize, labelfont=bf, skip=1ex]{caption}
%---------------- show page layoutdon't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\LTcapwidth=0.98\linewidth
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{}
                S[table-format=8.0]
                S[table-format=7.0]
                S[table-format=7.0]
                S[table-format=3.0]
                S[table-format=2.0]
           *{3}{S[table-format=2.1]}
                S[table-format=-4.0]
                @{} }
    \caption{\dots with Geol. fm. MAC \dots\\   
    \textbf{Legend:} Sandt.: Sandtone, Siltst.: Siltstone,
                     $R_\text{so}$: $R_\text{site(obs)}$,
                     $R_\text{soIRQ}$: $R_\text{site(obs)IQR}$
            }
    \label{tab:summary_camp_MAC} \\
    \toprule
{\thead{Survey\\ site code}}
     &  {\thead{Long\\ GB (m)}}
        &   {\thead{Lat\\ GB (m)}}
            &   {\thead{Sandt.\\(\%)}}%Sandtone
                &   {\thead{Siltst.\\(\%)}}%Siltstone
                    &   {\thead{$R_\text{so}$}}
                        &   {\thead{$R_\text{soIRQ}$}}
                            &   {\thead{$Mv$\\ (\%)}} & {GSI}    \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
    \caption[]{ (con.)\\
    \textbf{Legend:} Sandt.: Sandtone, Siltst.: Siltstone,
                     $R_\text{so}$: $R_\text{site(obs)}$,
                     $R_\text{soIRQ}$: $R_\text{site(obs)IQR}$
                }\\
    \toprule
{\thead{Survey\\ site code}}
     &  {\thead{Long\\ GB (m)}}
        &   {\thead{Lat\\ GB (m)}}
            &   {\thead{Sandt.\\(\%)}}%Sandtone
                &   {\thead{Siltst.\\(\%)}}%Siltstone
                    &   {\thead{$R_\text{so}$}}
                        &   {\thead{$R_\text{soIQR}$}}
                            &   {\thead{$Mv$\\ (\%)}} & {GSI}    \\
    \midrule
    \vspace*{-18pt}
\endhead
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \multicolumn{9}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continued on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
\addlinespace
20160007    &   1607690 &   4885250 &   100 &       &   15.4    &   3.9 &   8.3 & -9999 \\*
20160008    &   1616420 &   4892160 &   100 &       &   11.8    &  13.9 &  32.7 &    35 \\*
20160009    &   1617450 &   4892970 &   100 &       &   12.9    &   6.4 &  12.3 & -9999 \\*
20160028    &   1642450 &   4867020 &   80  &   20  &   11.8    &   4.8 &  33.3 &    45 \\  \addlinespace
20160054    &   1607510 &   4895540 &   100 &       &   9.4     &   5.8 &  26.0 &    40 \\*
20160055    &   1651750 &   4855650 &   85  &   15  &   6.4     &   3.5 &  60.5 &    15 \\*
20160058    &   1599670 &   4899700 &   100 &       &   16.1    &  10.2 &  24.3 &    35 \\*
20160064    &   1613750 &   4875080 &   100 &       &   8.9     &   6.4 &  40.5 &    40 \\  \addlinespace
20160065    &   1628850 &   4875430 &   100 &       &   19.9    &   9.1 &  18.0 &    50 \\*
20160067    &   1626270 &   4880370 &   100 &       &   10.9    &   7.9 &  31.5 &    40 \\*
20160089    &   1579370 &   4907480 &   100 &       &   17.3    &   6.3 &  18.5 &    35 \\*
20160094    &   1626920 &   4864650 &   85  &   15  &   15.4    &   4.9 &  11.8 &    45 \\  \addlinespace
20160099    &   1615920 &   4891250 &   100 &       &   11.8    &  10.3 &  29.5 &    40 \\*
20160102    &   1608230 &   4883910 &       &       &   11.3    &  13.4 &  30.3 &    50 \\*
20160103    &   1630270 &   4874830 &   100 &       &   11.2    &   9.8 &  27.3 &    40 \\*
20160111    &   1637300 &   4866700 &   100 &       &   26.3    &   5.8 &   2.5 &    50 \\
\addlinespace
20160116    &   1635020 &   4887380 &   100 &       &   24.6    &   7.6 &   5.8 &    45 \\*  20160125    &   1638850 &   4861050 &   100 &       &   12.9    &   9.4 &  55.5 &    35 \\*
20160126    &   1632580 &   4875200 &   100 &       &   17.7    &   9.9 &  16.3 &    45 \\*
20160132    &   1627950 &   4879380 &   100 &       &   23.7    &  13.7 &   9.0 &    70 \\
\addlinespace
20160140    &   1629620 &   4876660 &   100 &       &   12.4    &   6.2 &  23.3 &    45 \\*  20160161    &   1612630 &   4892280 &   90  &   10  &   10.6    &   8.1 &  37.8 &    40 \\*
20160179    &   1633200 &   4874750 &   100 &       &   15.8    &  16.5 &  22.3 &    45 \\*
20160180    &   1629130 &   4877660 &   20  &       &   11.7    &  13.4 &  36.8 &    35 \\
\addlinespace
20160187    &   1609870 &   4886470 &   100 &       &   34.5    &   9.0 &   1.3 &    60 \\*  20160189    &   1616110 &   4883040 &   100 &       &   32.9    &   3.1 &   0.3 &    60 \\*
20160190    &   1639440 &   4884930 &       &   30  &   8.6     &   6.1 &  46.5 &    45 \\*
20160192    &   1621280 &   4882190 &   100 &       &   28.3    &   8.3 &   0.3 &    60 \\
\addlinespace
20160199    &   1617480 &   4892980 &   100 &       &   21.0    &   7.4 &   1.3 &    50 \\* 20160212    &   1623080 &   4886120 &   95  &       &   15.6    &   3.7 &   3.3 &    40 \\*
20160215    &   1635030 &   4871590 &   50  &   10  &   15.3    &   6.2 &   7.0 &    35 \\*
20160216    &   1633810 &   4873860 &   100 &       &   14.2    &   5.9 &   7.5 &    35 \\  \addlinespace
20160228    &   1611490 &   4888050 &   90  &       &   28.7    &  17.5 &   4.5 &    60 \\* 20160230    &   1611900 &   4886400 &   100 &       &   24.4    &   15.2&   1.8 &    50 \\*
20160234    &   1649360 &   4859070 &   100 &       &   30.0    &   7.4 &   0.0 &    50 \\*
20160240    &   1628280 &   4885520 &   100 &       &   27.5    &  10.4 &   6.3 &    50 \\
\addlinespace
20160245    &   1606850 &   4886800 &   95  &       &   31.6    &  10.3 &   1.3 &    50 \\* 20160248    &   1604840 &   4897570 &   100 &       &   24.7    &   6.5 &  10.0 &    50 \\*
20160252    &   1604300 &   4899930 &   100 &       &   27.2    &  11.4 &   1.3 &    55 \\*
20160256    &   1610880 &   4872490 &   80  &   20  &   24.0    &   7.6 &  20.5 &    45 \\
\addlinespace
20160257    &   1603610 &   4889240 &   100 &       &   30.0    &   4.2 &   0.0 &    65 \\* 20160264    &   1617530 &   4890220 &   100 &       &   32.3    &   6.7 &   0.0 &    60 \\*
20160267    &   1632780 &   4889010 &   40  &       &   13.7    &  17.3 &  24.3 &    40 \\*
20160272    &   1636910 &   4887220 &   100 &       &   27.8    &   8.0 &   2.3 &    55 \\  \addlinespace
20160277    &   1589240 &   4878450 &   100 &       &   10.5    &   7.2 &  24.3 &    30 \\* 20160278    &   1589630 &   4878030 &   100 &       &   11.3    &   6.1 &  22.3 & -9999 \\*
20160279    &   1589360 &   4878090 &       &       &   14.9    &   9.7 &  21.8 & -9999 \\*
20160280    &   1589200 &   4878190 &   100 &       &   15.8    &   4.1 &   1.5 &    50 \\  \addlinespace
20160281    &   1588690 &   4878380 &   100 &       &    9.1    &   6.2 &  35.5 &    30 \\*  20160283    &   1586320 &   4881360 &   100 &       &   17.7    &  15.0 &  16.0 &    45 \\*
20160284    &   1585980 &   4881540 &   80  &       &   17.3    &   5.5 &   2.8 &    45 \\*
20160286    &   1588290 &   4878570 &   100 &       &   19.1    &   6.2 &   1.5 &    55 \\
\addlinespace
20170292    &   1592500 &   4892430 &       &       &   19.2    &   7.8 &   1.8 & -9999 \\*  20170293    &   1593630 &   4895890 &   100 &       &   28.8    &   7.9 &   0.0 & -9999 \\*
20170294    &   1592590 &   4896460 &   100 &       &   31.0    &   6.9 &   0.0 & -9999 \\*
20170295    &   1592350 &   4896370 &   100 &       &   19.7    &   9.9 &   3.5 & -9999 \\
\addlinespace
20170296    &   1592380 &   4905810 &   100 &       &   29.0    &   8.0 &   0.0 & -9999 \\*  20170297    &   1592400 &   4907000 &   70  &       &   15.0    &  13.3 &  31.8 & -9999 \\*
20170298    &   1592170 &   4906530 &   70  &       &   10.1    &  12.3 &  45.3 & -9999 \\*
20170299    &   1594910 &   4891490 &   90  &       &   29.7    &   9.9 &   0.3 & -9999 \\
\addlinespace
20170300    &   1585800 &   4887720 &   90  &       &   31.1    &   6.3 &   2.3 & -9999 \\*  20170302    &   1584720 &   4886610 &   75  &       &   30.0    &  11.6 &   3.8 & -9999 \\*
20170303    &   1592340 &   4891340 &   60  &       &   27.7    &  11.9 &   5.5 & -9999 \\*
20170304    &   1584520 &   4885990 &   85  &       &   18.6    &   5.0 &   4.0 & -9999 \\
\addlinespace
20170305    &   1579960 &   4888640 &   100 &       &   16.0    &   6.8 &   2.0 & -9999 \\*  20170306    &   1582470 &   4887480 &   100 &       &   12.8    &   3.2 &   1.3 & -9999 \\*
20170311    &   1572640 &   4900500 &   85  &   15  &   32.3    &  17.0 &   9.0 & -9999 \\*
20170312    &   1569670 &   4900420 &   95  &       &   41.5    &   5.6 &   0.0 & -9999 \\ \addlinespace
20170313    &   1568040 &   4908720 &   90  &       &   38.4    &  13.1 &   3.8 & -9999 \\*  20170314    &   1569090 &   4909490 &   80  &   20  &   29.2    &   9.3 &   6.8 & -9999 \\*
20170315    &   1570460 &   4907080 &   50  &       &   22.5    &  11.5 &   1.8 & -9999 \\*
20170319    &   1568360 &   4905170 &   70  &   30  &   7.2     &   5.4 &  45.8 & -9999 \\
\addlinespace
20170320    &   1587250 &   4908030 &   90  &   10  &   24.0    &  13.8 &  19.8 & -9999 \\* 20170321    &   1577010 &   4912650 &   100 &       &   21.0    &   6.1 &   0.3 & -9999 \\*
20170322    &   1569040 &   4911210 &   95  &       &   12.9    &   5.0 &  12.0 & -9999 \\*
20170324    &   1567700 &   4910090 &   100 &       &   21.9    &   7.3 &   0.5 & -9999 \\ \addlinespace
20170325    &   1575160 &   4913620 &   100 &       &   24.5    &  16.8 &  16.8 & -9999 \\*
20170326    &   1578770 &   4913330 &   100 &       &   21.7    &  12.8 &   2.3 & -9999 \\*
20170327    &   1583430 &   4909340 &   100 &       &   27.5    &   7.4 &   0.8 & -9999 \\*
20170328    &   1564440 &   4909900 &   100 &       &   23.5    &   5.4 &   0.0 & -9999 \\ \addlinespace
20170329    &   1561890 &   4910980 &   100 &       &   32.7    &   7.9 &   0.3 & -9999 \\*
20170330    &   1558500 &   4909390 &   100 &       &   25.2    &   8.4 &   0.0 & -9999 \\*
20170331    &   1564360 &   4907210 &   100 &       &   19.6    &  19.7 &  23.5 & -9999 \\*
20170332    &   1571290 &   4918160 &   100 &       &   28.8    &   6.6 &   2.3 & -9999 \\
\addlinespace
20170333    &   1570430 &   4918290 &   95  &       &   23.6    &   5.6 &   0.0 & -9999 \\* 20170334    &   1565530 &   4919120 &   90  &       &   18.4    &   8.7 &  20.5 & -9999 \\*
20170335    &   1565100 &   4915610 &   100 &       &   15.1    &   6.8 &   9.8 & -9999 \\*
20170336    &   1568760 &   4918440 &   100 &       &   26.5    &  13.9 &  12.0 & -9999 \\
\addlinespace
20170337    &   1563570 &   4906190 &   100 &       &   24.8    &   7.5 &   1.5 & -9999 \\*  20170341    &   1579920 &   4890580 &   100 &       &   28.6    &   4.5 &   0.3 & -9999 \\*
20170342    &   1579640 &   4891250 &   100 &       &   18.8    &  11.2 &  73.8 & -9999 \\*
20170344    &   1589220 &   4890470 &   100 &       &   25.9    &   8.0 &   1.0 & -9999 \\
\addlinespace
20170329    &   1561890 &   4910980 &   100 &       &   32.7    &   7.9 &   0.3 & -9999 \\*
20170346    &   1572260 &   4918250 &   100 &       &   19.3    &  12.0 &  18.8 & -9999 \\*
20170329    &   1561890 &   4910980 &   100 &       &   32.7    &   7.9 &   0.3 & -9999 \\*   20170347    &   1575560 &   4919100 &   100 &       &   30.7    &  12.6 &   0.3 & -9999 \\
\addlinespace
20170329    &   1561890 &   4910980 &   100 &       &   32.7    &   7.9 &   0.3 & -9999 \\*
20171007    &   1592610 &   4905140 &   100 &       &   25.1    &   6.4 &   2.8 &    50 \\*
20170329    &   1561890 &   4910980 &   100 &       &   32.7    &   7.9 &   0.3 & -9999 \\*
20171015    &   1594430 &   4895710 &   100 &       &   16.7    &  12.3 &  14.5 &    35 \\ 
\addlinespace
20170329    &   1561890 &   4910980 &   100 &       &   32.7    &   7.9 &   0.3 & -9999 \\*
20171016    &   1594060 &   4892390 &   100 &       &   16.9    &   7.2 &  11.5 &    40 \\*  20171017    &   1593560 &   4892350 &   100 &       &   16.9    &   7.2 &  11.5 &    50 \\*
20170329    &   1561890 &   4910980 &   100 &       &   32.7    &   7.9 &   0.3 & -9999 \\
\addlinespace
20171020    &   1569820 &   4908340 &   100 &       &   27.6    &   5.0 &   0.5 &    60 \\*  
20170329    &   1561890 &   4910980 &   100 &       &   32.7    &   7.9 &   0.3 & -9999 \\*
20171021    &   1568030 &   4907030 &   100 &       &   23.2    &  11.2 &   1.0 &    45 \\*  
20170329    &   1561890 &   4910980 &   100 &       &   32.7    &   7.9 &   0.3 & -9999 \\
\addlinespace
20171022    &   1567060 &   4905870 &   50  &   40  &   17.5    &  23.8 &  38.3 &    35 \\*
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders.

Answer (score 3):

Probably one of the following suits your needs. I'd use the first one since the font size on the second example is extremely small:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
    \usepackage{booktabs, dcolumn, makecell,               
        longtable, tabularx,siunitx,setspace,pdflscape}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalfont}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{S[table-format=8.0]S[table-format=7.0]S[table-format=7.0]c S[table-format=3.0] S[table-format=2.0]S[table-format=2.1] S[table-format=2.1]S[table-format=2.1]S[table-format=-4.0]
    }
    \caption{}
    \label{tab:summary_camp_MAC} \\
    \toprule
    {\thead{Survey site\\ code}}& {\thead{Long\\ GB (m)}}& {\thead{Lat\\ GB (m)}} &\thead{Geol.\\ fm.}& {\thead{Sandtone\\(\%)}}& {\thead{Siltstone\\(\%)}}&{$R_{site(obs)}$} & {$R_{site(obs)IQR}$}& {$ Mv\%$}& {GSI}\\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    \caption[]{}\\        
    \toprule
    {\thead{Survey site\\ code}}& {\thead{Long\\ GB (m)}}& {\thead{Lat\\ GB (m)}} &\thead{Geol.\\ fm.}& {\thead{Sandtone\\(\%)}}& {\thead{Siltstone\\(\%)}}&{$R_{site(obs)}$} & {$R_{site(obs)IQR}$}& {$ Mv\%$}& {GSI}\\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \multicolumn{10}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continued on the next page}}
    \endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    20160007    &   1607690 &   4885250 &   MAC &   100 &       &   15.4    &   3.9 &   8.3 &   -9999   \\
    20160008    &   1616420 &   4892160 &   MAC &   100 &       &   11.8    &   13.9    &   32.7    &   35  \\
    20160009    &   1617450 &   4892970 &   MAC &   100 &       &   12.9    &   6.4 &   12.3    &   -9999   \\
    20160028    &   1642450 &   4867020 &   MAC &   80  &   20  &   11.8    &   4.8 &   33.3    &   45  \\
    20160054    &   1607510 &   4895540 &   MAC &   100 &       &   9.4 &   5.8 &   26.0    &   40  \\
    20160055    &   1651750 &   4855650 &   MAC &   85  &   15  &   6.4 &   3.5 &   60.5    &   15  \\
    20160058    &   1599670 &   4899700 &   MAC &   100 &       &   16.1    &   10.2    &   24.3    &   35  \\
    20160064    &   1613750 &   4875080 &   MAC &   100 &       &   8.9 &   6.4 &   40.5    &   40  \\
    20160065    &   1628850 &   4875430 &   MAC &   100 &       &   19.9    &   9.1 &   18.0    &   50  \\
    20160067    &   1626270 &   4880370 &   MAC &   100 &       &   10.9    &   7.9 &   31.5    &   40  \\
    20160089    &   1579370 &   4907480 &   MAC &   100 &       &   17.3    &   6.3 &   18.5    &   35  \\
    20160094    &   1626920 &   4864650 &   MAC &   85  &   15  &   15.4    &   4.9 &   11.8    &   45  \\
    20160099    &   1615920 &   4891250 &   MAC &   100 &       &   11.8    &   10.3    &   29.5    &   40  \\
    20160102    &   1608230 &   4883910 &   MAC &       &       &   11.3    &   13.4    &   30.3    &   50  \\
    20160103    &   1630270 &   4874830 &   MAC &   100 &       &   11.2    &   9.8 &   27.3    &   40  \\
    20160111    &   1637300 &   4866700 &   MAC &   100 &       &   26.3    &   5.8 &   2.5 &   50  \\
    20160116    &   1635020 &   4887380 &   MAC &   100 &       &   24.6    &   7.6 &   5.8 &   45  \\
    20160125    &   1638850 &   4861050 &   MAC &   100 &       &   12.9    &   9.4 &   55.5    &   35  \\
    20160126    &   1632580 &   4875200 &   MAC &   100 &       &   17.7    &   9.9 &   16.3    &   45  \\
    20160132    &   1627950 &   4879380 &   MAC &   100 &       &   23.7    &   13.7    &   9.0 &   70  \\
    20160140    &   1629620 &   4876660 &   MAC &   100 &       &   12.4    &   6.2 &   23.3    &   45  \\
    20160161    &   1612630 &   4892280 &   MAC &   90  &   10  &   10.6    &   8.1 &   37.8    &   40  \\
    20160179    &   1633200 &   4874750 &   MAC &   100 &       &   15.8    &   16.5    &   22.3    &   45  \\
    20160180    &   1629130 &   4877660 &   MAC &   20  &       &   11.7    &   13.4    &   36.8    &   35  \\
    20160187    &   1609870 &   4886470 &   MAC &   100 &       &   34.5    &   9.0 &   1.3 &   60  \\
    20160189    &   1616110 &   4883040 &   MAC &   100 &       &   32.9    &   3.1 &   0.3 &   60  \\
    20160190    &   1639440 &   4884930 &   MAC &       &   30  &   8.6 &   6.1 &   46.5    &   45  \\
    20160192    &   1621280 &   4882190 &   MAC &   100 &       &   28.3    &   8.3 &   0.3 &   60  \\
    20160199    &   1617480 &   4892980 &   MAC &   100 &       &   21.0    &   7.4 &   1.3 &   50  \\
    20160212    &   1623080 &   4886120 &   MAC &   95  &       &   15.6    &   3.7 &   3.3 &   40  \\
    20160215    &   1635030 &   4871590 &   MAC &   50  &   10  &   15.3    &   6.2 &   7.0 &   35  \\
    20160216    &   1633810 &   4873860 &   MAC &   100 &       &   14.2    &   5.9 &   7.5 &   35  \\
    20160228    &   1611490 &   4888050 &   MAC &   90  &       &   28.7    &   17.5    &   4.5 &   60  \\
    20160230    &   1611900 &   4886400 &   MAC &   100 &       &   24.4    &   15.2    &   1.8 &   50  \\
    20160234    &   1649360 &   4859070 &   MAC &   100 &       &   30.0    &   7.4 &   0.0 &   50  \\
    20160240    &   1628280 &   4885520 &   MAC &   100 &       &   27.5    &   10.4    &   6.3 &   50  \\
    20160245    &   1606850 &   4886800 &   MAC &   95  &       &   31.6    &   10.3    &   1.3 &   50  \\
    20160248    &   1604840 &   4897570 &   MAC &   100 &       &   24.7    &   6.5 &   10.0    &   50  \\
    20160252    &   1604300 &   4899930 &   MAC &   100 &       &   27.2    &   11.4    &   1.3 &   55  \\
    20160256    &   1610880 &   4872490 &   MAC &   80  &   20  &   24.0    &   7.6 &   20.5    &   45  \\
    20160257    &   1603610 &   4889240 &   MAC &   100 &       &   30.0    &   4.2 &   0.0 &   65  \\
    20160264    &   1617530 &   4890220 &   MAC &   100 &       &   32.3    &   6.7 &   0.0 &   60  \\
    20160267    &   1632780 &   4889010 &   MAC &   40  &       &   13.7    &   17.3    &   24.3    &   40  \\
    20160272    &   1636910 &   4887220 &   MAC &   100 &       &   27.8    &   8.0 &   2.3 &   55  \\
    20160277    &   1589240 &   4878450 &   MAC &   100 &       &   10.5    &   7.2 &   24.3    &   30  \\
    20160278    &   1589630 &   4878030 &   MAC &   100 &       &   11.3    &   6.1 &   22.3    &   -9999   \\
    20160279    &   1589360 &   4878090 &   MAC &       &       &   14.9    &   9.7 &   21.8    &   -9999   \\
    20160280    &   1589200 &   4878190 &   MAC &   100 &       &   15.8    &   4.1 &   1.5 &   50  \\
    20160281    &   1588690 &   4878380 &   MAC &   100 &       &   9.1 &   6.2 &   35.5    &   30  \\
    20160283    &   1586320 &   4881360 &   MAC &   100 &       &   17.7    &   15.0    &   16.0    &   45  \\
    20160284    &   1585980 &   4881540 &   MAC &   80  &       &   17.3    &   5.5 &   2.8 &   45  \\
    20160286    &   1588290 &   4878570 &   MAC &   100 &       &   19.1    &   6.2 &   1.5 &   55  \\
    20170292    &   1592500 &   4892430 &   MAC &       &       &   19.2    &   7.8 &   1.8 &   -9999   \\
    20170293    &   1593630 &   4895890 &   MAC &   100 &       &   28.8    &   7.9 &   0.0 &   -9999   \\
    20170294    &   1592590 &   4896460 &   MAC &   100 &       &   31.0    &   6.9 &   0.0 &   -9999   \\
    20170295    &   1592350 &   4896370 &   MAC &   100 &       &   19.7    &   9.9 &   3.5 &   -9999   \\
    20170296    &   1592380 &   4905810 &   MAC &   100 &       &   29.0    &   8.0 &   0.0 &   -9999   \\
    20170297    &   1592400 &   4907000 &   MAC &   70  &       &   15.0    &   13.3    &   31.8    &   -9999   \\
    20170298    &   1592170 &   4906530 &   MAC &   70  &       &   10.1    &   12.3    &   45.3    &   -9999   \\
    20170299    &   1594910 &   4891490 &   MAC &   90  &       &   29.7    &   9.9 &   0.3 &   -9999   \\
    20170300    &   1585800 &   4887720 &   MAC &   90  &       &   31.1    &   6.3 &   2.3 &   -9999   \\
    20170302    &   1584720 &   4886610 &   MAC &   75  &       &   30.0    &   11.6    &   3.8 &   -9999   \\
    20170303    &   1592340 &   4891340 &   MAC &   60  &       &   27.7    &   11.9    &   5.5 &   -9999   \\
    20170304    &   1584520 &   4885990 &   MAC &   85  &       &   18.6    &   5.0 &   4.0 &   -9999   \\
    20170305    &   1579960 &   4888640 &   MAC &   100 &       &   16.0    &   6.8 &   2.0 &   -9999   \\
    20170306    &   1582470 &   4887480 &   MAC &   100 &       &   12.8    &   3.2 &   1.3 &   -9999   \\
    20170311    &   1572640 &   4900500 &   MAC &   85  &   15  &   32.3    &   17.0    &   9.0 &   -9999   \\
    20170312    &   1569670 &   4900420 &   MAC &   95  &       &   41.5    &   5.6 &   0.0 &   -9999   \\
    20170313    &   1568040 &   4908720 &   MAC &   90  &       &   38.4    &   13.1    &   3.8 &   -9999   \\
    20170314    &   1569090 &   4909490 &   MAC &   80  &   20  &   29.2    &   9.3 &   6.8 &   -9999   \\
    20170315    &   1570460 &   4907080 &   MAC &   50  &       &   22.5    &   11.5    &   1.8 &   -9999   \\
    20170319    &   1568360 &   4905170 &   MAC &   70  &   30  &   7.2 &   5.4 &   45.8    &   -9999   \\
    20170320    &   1587250 &   4908030 &   MAC &   90  &   10  &   24.0    &   13.8    &   19.8    &   -9999   \\
    20170321    &   1577010 &   4912650 &   MAC &   100 &       &   21.0    &   6.1 &   0.3 &   -9999   \\
    20170322    &   1569040 &   4911210 &   MAC &   95  &       &   12.9    &   5.0 &   12.0    &   -9999   \\
    20170324    &   1567700 &   4910090 &   MAC &   100 &       &   21.9    &   7.3 &   0.5 &   -9999   \\
    20170325    &   1575160 &   4913620 &   MAC &   100 &       &   24.5    &   16.8    &   16.8    &   -9999   \\
    20170326    &   1578770 &   4913330 &   MAC &   100 &       &   21.7    &   12.8    &   2.3 &   -9999   \\
    20170327    &   1583430 &   4909340 &   MAC &   100 &       &   27.5    &   7.4 &   0.8 &   -9999   \\
    20170328    &   1564440 &   4909900 &   MAC &   100 &       &   23.5    &   5.4 &   0.0 &   -9999   \\
    20170329    &   1561890 &   4910980 &   MAC &   100 &       &   32.7    &   7.9 &   0.3 &   -9999   \\
    20170330    &   1558500 &   4909390 &   MAC &   100 &       &   25.2    &   8.4 &   0.0 &   -9999   \\
    20170331    &   1564360 &   4907210 &   MAC &   100 &       &   19.6    &   19.7    &   23.5    &   -9999   \\
    20170332    &   1571290 &   4918160 &   MAC &   100 &       &   28.8    &   6.6 &   2.3 &   -9999   \\
    20170333    &   1570430 &   4918290 &   MAC &   95  &       &   23.6    &   5.6 &   0.0 &   -9999   \\
    20170334    &   1565530 &   4919120 &   MAC &   90  &       &   18.4    &   8.7 &   20.5    &   -9999   \\
    20170335    &   1565100 &   4915610 &   MAC &   100 &       &   15.1    &   6.8 &   9.8 &   -9999   \\
    20170336    &   1568760 &   4918440 &   MAC &   100 &       &   26.5    &   13.9    &   12.0    &   -9999   \\
    20170337    &   1563570 &   4906190 &   MAC &   100 &       &   24.8    &   7.5 &   1.5 &   -9999   \\
    20170341    &   1579920 &   4890580 &   MAC &   100 &       &   28.6    &   4.5 &   0.3 &   -9999   \\
    20170342    &   1579640 &   4891250 &   MAC &   100 &       &   18.8    &   11.2    &   73.8    &   -9999   \\
    20170344    &   1589220 &   4890470 &   MAC &   100 &       &   25.9    &   8.0 &   1.0 &   -9999   \\
    20170346    &   1572260 &   4918250 &   MAC &   100 &       &   19.3    &   12.0    &   18.8    &   -9999   \\
    20170347    &   1575560 &   4919100 &   MAC &   100 &       &   30.7    &   12.6    &   0.3 &   -9999   \\
    20171007    &   1592610 &   4905140 &   MAC &   100 &       &   25.1    &   6.4 &   2.8 &   50  \\
    20171015    &   1594430 &   4895710 &   MAC &   100 &       &   16.7    &   12.3    &   14.5    &   35  \\
    20171016    &   1594060 &   4892390 &   MAC &   100 &       &   16.9    &   7.2 &   11.5    &   40  \\
    20171017    &   1593560 &   4892350 &   MAC &   100 &       &   16.9    &   7.2 &   11.5    &   50  \\
    20171020    &   1569820 &   4908340 &   MAC &   100 &       &   27.6    &   5.0 &   0.5 &   60  \\
    20171021    &   1568030 &   4907030 &   MAC &   100 &       &   23.2    &   11.2    &   1.0 &   45  \\
    20171022    &   1567060 &   4905870 &   MAC &   50  &   40  &   17.5    &   23.8    &   38.3    &   35  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}


\scriptsize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.75pt}
\begin{longtable}{S[table-format=8.0]S[table-format=7.0]S[table-format=7.0]c S[table-format=3.0] S[table-format=2.0]S[table-format=2.1] S[table-format=2.1]S[table-format=2.1]S[table-format=-4.0]
    }
    \caption{}
    \label{tab:summary_camp_MAC} \\
    \toprule
    {\thead{Survey site\\ code}}& {\thead{Long\\ GB (m)}}& {\thead{Lat\\ GB (m)}} &\thead{Geol.\\ fm.}& {\thead{Sandtone\\(\%)}}& {\thead{Siltstone\\(\%)}}&{$R_{site(obs)}$} & {$R_{site(obs)IQR}$}& {$ Mv\%$}& {GSI}\\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    \caption[]{}\\        
    \toprule
    {\thead{Survey site\\ code}}& {\thead{Long\\ GB (m)}}& {\thead{Lat\\ GB (m)}} &\thead{Geol.\\ fm.}& {\thead{Sandtone\\(\%)}}& {\thead{Siltstone\\(\%)}}&{$R_{site(obs)}$} & {$R_{site(obs)IQR}$}& {$ Mv\%$}& {GSI}\\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \multicolumn{10}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continued on the next page}}
    \endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    20160007    &   1607690 &   4885250 &   MAC &   100 &       &   15.4    &   3.9 &   8.3 &   -9999   \\
    20160008    &   1616420 &   4892160 &   MAC &   100 &       &   11.8    &   13.9    &   32.7    &   35  \\
    20160009    &   1617450 &   4892970 &   MAC &   100 &       &   12.9    &   6.4 &   12.3    &   -9999   \\
    20160028    &   1642450 &   4867020 &   MAC &   80  &   20  &   11.8    &   4.8 &   33.3    &   45  \\
    20160054    &   1607510 &   4895540 &   MAC &   100 &       &   9.4 &   5.8 &   26.0    &   40  \\
    20160055    &   1651750 &   4855650 &   MAC &   85  &   15  &   6.4 &   3.5 &   60.5    &   15  \\
    20160058    &   1599670 &   4899700 &   MAC &   100 &       &   16.1    &   10.2    &   24.3    &   35  \\
    20160064    &   1613750 &   4875080 &   MAC &   100 &       &   8.9 &   6.4 &   40.5    &   40  \\
    20160065    &   1628850 &   4875430 &   MAC &   100 &       &   19.9    &   9.1 &   18.0    &   50  \\
    20160067    &   1626270 &   4880370 &   MAC &   100 &       &   10.9    &   7.9 &   31.5    &   40  \\
    20160089    &   1579370 &   4907480 &   MAC &   100 &       &   17.3    &   6.3 &   18.5    &   35  \\
    20160094    &   1626920 &   4864650 &   MAC &   85  &   15  &   15.4    &   4.9 &   11.8    &   45  \\
    20160099    &   1615920 &   4891250 &   MAC &   100 &       &   11.8    &   10.3    &   29.5    &   40  \\
    20160102    &   1608230 &   4883910 &   MAC &       &       &   11.3    &   13.4    &   30.3    &   50  \\
    20160103    &   1630270 &   4874830 &   MAC &   100 &       &   11.2    &   9.8 &   27.3    &   40  \\
    20160111    &   1637300 &   4866700 &   MAC &   100 &       &   26.3    &   5.8 &   2.5 &   50  \\
    20160116    &   1635020 &   4887380 &   MAC &   100 &       &   24.6    &   7.6 &   5.8 &   45  \\
    20160125    &   1638850 &   4861050 &   MAC &   100 &       &   12.9    &   9.4 &   55.5    &   35  \\
    20160126    &   1632580 &   4875200 &   MAC &   100 &       &   17.7    &   9.9 &   16.3    &   45  \\
    20160132    &   1627950 &   4879380 &   MAC &   100 &       &   23.7    &   13.7    &   9.0 &   70  \\
    20160140    &   1629620 &   4876660 &   MAC &   100 &       &   12.4    &   6.2 &   23.3    &   45  \\
    20160161    &   1612630 &   4892280 &   MAC &   90  &   10  &   10.6    &   8.1 &   37.8    &   40  \\
    20160179    &   1633200 &   4874750 &   MAC &   100 &       &   15.8    &   16.5    &   22.3    &   45  \\
    20160180    &   1629130 &   4877660 &   MAC &   20  &       &   11.7    &   13.4    &   36.8    &   35  \\
    20160187    &   1609870 &   4886470 &   MAC &   100 &       &   34.5    &   9.0 &   1.3 &   60  \\
    20160189    &   1616110 &   4883040 &   MAC &   100 &       &   32.9    &   3.1 &   0.3 &   60  \\
    20160190    &   1639440 &   4884930 &   MAC &       &   30  &   8.6 &   6.1 &   46.5    &   45  \\
    20160192    &   1621280 &   4882190 &   MAC &   100 &       &   28.3    &   8.3 &   0.3 &   60  \\
    20160199    &   1617480 &   4892980 &   MAC &   100 &       &   21.0    &   7.4 &   1.3 &   50  \\
    20160212    &   1623080 &   4886120 &   MAC &   95  &       &   15.6    &   3.7 &   3.3 &   40  \\
    20160215    &   1635030 &   4871590 &   MAC &   50  &   10  &   15.3    &   6.2 &   7.0 &   35  \\
    20160216    &   1633810 &   4873860 &   MAC &   100 &       &   14.2    &   5.9 &   7.5 &   35  \\
    20160228    &   1611490 &   4888050 &   MAC &   90  &       &   28.7    &   17.5    &   4.5 &   60  \\
    20160230    &   1611900 &   4886400 &   MAC &   100 &       &   24.4    &   15.2    &   1.8 &   50  \\
    20160234    &   1649360 &   4859070 &   MAC &   100 &       &   30.0    &   7.4 &   0.0 &   50  \\
    20160240    &   1628280 &   4885520 &   MAC &   100 &       &   27.5    &   10.4    &   6.3 &   50  \\
    20160245    &   1606850 &   4886800 &   MAC &   95  &       &   31.6    &   10.3    &   1.3 &   50  \\
    20160248    &   1604840 &   4897570 &   MAC &   100 &       &   24.7    &   6.5 &   10.0    &   50  \\
    20160252    &   1604300 &   4899930 &   MAC &   100 &       &   27.2    &   11.4    &   1.3 &   55  \\
    20160256    &   1610880 &   4872490 &   MAC &   80  &   20  &   24.0    &   7.6 &   20.5    &   45  \\
    20160257    &   1603610 &   4889240 &   MAC &   100 &       &   30.0    &   4.2 &   0.0 &   65  \\
    20160264    &   1617530 &   4890220 &   MAC &   100 &       &   32.3    &   6.7 &   0.0 &   60  \\
    20160267    &   1632780 &   4889010 &   MAC &   40  &       &   13.7    &   17.3    &   24.3    &   40  \\
    20160272    &   1636910 &   4887220 &   MAC &   100 &       &   27.8    &   8.0 &   2.3 &   55  \\
    20160277    &   1589240 &   4878450 &   MAC &   100 &       &   10.5    &   7.2 &   24.3    &   30  \\
    20160278    &   1589630 &   4878030 &   MAC &   100 &       &   11.3    &   6.1 &   22.3    &   -9999   \\
    20160279    &   1589360 &   4878090 &   MAC &       &       &   14.9    &   9.7 &   21.8    &   -9999   \\
    20160280    &   1589200 &   4878190 &   MAC &   100 &       &   15.8    &   4.1 &   1.5 &   50  \\
    20160281    &   1588690 &   4878380 &   MAC &   100 &       &   9.1 &   6.2 &   35.5    &   30  \\
    20160283    &   1586320 &   4881360 &   MAC &   100 &       &   17.7    &   15.0    &   16.0    &   45  \\
    20160284    &   1585980 &   4881540 &   MAC &   80  &       &   17.3    &   5.5 &   2.8 &   45  \\
    20160286    &   1588290 &   4878570 &   MAC &   100 &       &   19.1    &   6.2 &   1.5 &   55  \\
    20170292    &   1592500 &   4892430 &   MAC &       &       &   19.2    &   7.8 &   1.8 &   -9999   \\
    20170293    &   1593630 &   4895890 &   MAC &   100 &       &   28.8    &   7.9 &   0.0 &   -9999   \\
    20170294    &   1592590 &   4896460 &   MAC &   100 &       &   31.0    &   6.9 &   0.0 &   -9999   \\
    20170295    &   1592350 &   4896370 &   MAC &   100 &       &   19.7    &   9.9 &   3.5 &   -9999   \\
    20170296    &   1592380 &   4905810 &   MAC &   100 &       &   29.0    &   8.0 &   0.0 &   -9999   \\
    20170297    &   1592400 &   4907000 &   MAC &   70  &       &   15.0    &   13.3    &   31.8    &   -9999   \\
    20170298    &   1592170 &   4906530 &   MAC &   70  &       &   10.1    &   12.3    &   45.3    &   -9999   \\
    20170299    &   1594910 &   4891490 &   MAC &   90  &       &   29.7    &   9.9 &   0.3 &   -9999   \\
    20170300    &   1585800 &   4887720 &   MAC &   90  &       &   31.1    &   6.3 &   2.3 &   -9999   \\
    20170302    &   1584720 &   4886610 &   MAC &   75  &       &   30.0    &   11.6    &   3.8 &   -9999   \\
    20170303    &   1592340 &   4891340 &   MAC &   60  &       &   27.7    &   11.9    &   5.5 &   -9999   \\
    20170304    &   1584520 &   4885990 &   MAC &   85  &       &   18.6    &   5.0 &   4.0 &   -9999   \\
    20170305    &   1579960 &   4888640 &   MAC &   100 &       &   16.0    &   6.8 &   2.0 &   -9999   \\
    20170306    &   1582470 &   4887480 &   MAC &   100 &       &   12.8    &   3.2 &   1.3 &   -9999   \\
    20170311    &   1572640 &   4900500 &   MAC &   85  &   15  &   32.3    &   17.0    &   9.0 &   -9999   \\
    20170312    &   1569670 &   4900420 &   MAC &   95  &       &   41.5    &   5.6 &   0.0 &   -9999   \\
    20170313    &   1568040 &   4908720 &   MAC &   90  &       &   38.4    &   13.1    &   3.8 &   -9999   \\
    20170314    &   1569090 &   4909490 &   MAC &   80  &   20  &   29.2    &   9.3 &   6.8 &   -9999   \\
    20170315    &   1570460 &   4907080 &   MAC &   50  &       &   22.5    &   11.5    &   1.8 &   -9999   \\
    20170319    &   1568360 &   4905170 &   MAC &   70  &   30  &   7.2 &   5.4 &   45.8    &   -9999   \\
    20170320    &   1587250 &   4908030 &   MAC &   90  &   10  &   24.0    &   13.8    &   19.8    &   -9999   \\
    20170321    &   1577010 &   4912650 &   MAC &   100 &       &   21.0    &   6.1 &   0.3 &   -9999   \\
    20170322    &   1569040 &   4911210 &   MAC &   95  &       &   12.9    &   5.0 &   12.0    &   -9999   \\
    20170324    &   1567700 &   4910090 &   MAC &   100 &       &   21.9    &   7.3 &   0.5 &   -9999   \\
    20170325    &   1575160 &   4913620 &   MAC &   100 &       &   24.5    &   16.8    &   16.8    &   -9999   \\
    20170326    &   1578770 &   4913330 &   MAC &   100 &       &   21.7    &   12.8    &   2.3 &   -9999   \\
    20170327    &   1583430 &   4909340 &   MAC &   100 &       &   27.5    &   7.4 &   0.8 &   -9999   \\
    20170328    &   1564440 &   4909900 &   MAC &   100 &       &   23.5    &   5.4 &   0.0 &   -9999   \\
    20170329    &   1561890 &   4910980 &   MAC &   100 &       &   32.7    &   7.9 &   0.3 &   -9999   \\
    20170330    &   1558500 &   4909390 &   MAC &   100 &       &   25.2    &   8.4 &   0.0 &   -9999   \\
    20170331    &   1564360 &   4907210 &   MAC &   100 &       &   19.6    &   19.7    &   23.5    &   -9999   \\
    20170332    &   1571290 &   4918160 &   MAC &   100 &       &   28.8    &   6.6 &   2.3 &   -9999   \\
    20170333    &   1570430 &   4918290 &   MAC &   95  &       &   23.6    &   5.6 &   0.0 &   -9999   \\
    20170334    &   1565530 &   4919120 &   MAC &   90  &       &   18.4    &   8.7 &   20.5    &   -9999   \\
    20170335    &   1565100 &   4915610 &   MAC &   100 &       &   15.1    &   6.8 &   9.8 &   -9999   \\
    20170336    &   1568760 &   4918440 &   MAC &   100 &       &   26.5    &   13.9    &   12.0    &   -9999   \\
    20170337    &   1563570 &   4906190 &   MAC &   100 &       &   24.8    &   7.5 &   1.5 &   -9999   \\
    20170341    &   1579920 &   4890580 &   MAC &   100 &       &   28.6    &   4.5 &   0.3 &   -9999   \\
    20170342    &   1579640 &   4891250 &   MAC &   100 &       &   18.8    &   11.2    &   73.8    &   -9999   \\
    20170344    &   1589220 &   4890470 &   MAC &   100 &       &   25.9    &   8.0 &   1.0 &   -9999   \\
    20170346    &   1572260 &   4918250 &   MAC &   100 &       &   19.3    &   12.0    &   18.8    &   -9999   \\
    20170347    &   1575560 &   4919100 &   MAC &   100 &       &   30.7    &   12.6    &   0.3 &   -9999   \\
    20171007    &   1592610 &   4905140 &   MAC &   100 &       &   25.1    &   6.4 &   2.8 &   50  \\
    20171015    &   1594430 &   4895710 &   MAC &   100 &       &   16.7    &   12.3    &   14.5    &   35  \\
    20171016    &   1594060 &   4892390 &   MAC &   100 &       &   16.9    &   7.2 &   11.5    &   40  \\
    20171017    &   1593560 &   4892350 &   MAC &   100 &       &   16.9    &   7.2 &   11.5    &   50  \\
    20171020    &   1569820 &   4908340 &   MAC &   100 &       &   27.6    &   5.0 &   0.5 &   60  \\
    20171021    &   1568030 &   4907030 &   MAC &   100 &       &   23.2    &   11.2    &   1.0 &   45  \\
    20171022    &   1567060 &   4905870 &   MAC &   50  &   40  &   17.5    &   23.8    &   38.3    &   35  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```